# Reading from file and sort into subsets

Tags: java, sorting

I am working on a project where I need to read a bunch of floating point integers from a file and sort them into subsets. The subsets need to be sorted by their distance apart. I need to first pull the first element out of the file and use that as the distance comparison d. Then take the next element a and put it into a separate list to be compared, then read the third element b and compare it with a. b needs to be at least d apart from a, if so it would be put into the subset with a. Then b would equal a and you would move on down till the end and make those a set, then you would start over and do it again until there are no more elements.

I am trying to do this by using array lists, all I have so far is reading the file and putting it into an array list then sorting it. I need some help with pulling the first element out and then making the comparisons.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;

public class FloatFromFile
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner file = null;
    ArrayList<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();

    try
    {
        file = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while(file.hasNext())
    {
        if (file.hasNextFloat()) list.add(file.nextFloat());
        else file.next();
    }

    // display unsorted list
    System.err.print("Origional List is:\n");
    for (Float i: list) System.out.println(i);

    Collections.sort(list);

    // display sorted list
    System.err.print("Sorted List is:\n");
    for (Float i: list) System.out.println(i);

            ArrayList<Float> sorted = new ArrayList<Float>();
    while (file.hasNext())
    {
        Float val = file.nextFloat();
        int i = sorted.size();
        float temp = sorted.get(i-1);
        while (i > 0 && temp > val)
        {
            i--;
            temp = sorted.get(i-1);
        }
        sorted.insert(i, val);
    }
    for (Float i: sorted) System.out.println(i);

    }
}
```

I added in the new method, but I am still having problems getting it to work
I am getting the errors

FloatFromFile.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
sorted.insert(i,val);
      ^
symbol: method insert(int,Float)
location: variable sorted of type ArrayList
1 error

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: What's a floating point integer?

Answer (score 0):

There are [many sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) that you can try. You could use insertion sort since you're going to be going through each element one by one anyway.

```
List<Float> sorted = new ArrayList<Float>();
while (file.hasNext()) {
  float val = file.nextFloat();
  int i = sorted.size();
  if (i == 0) {
    sorted.add(val);
    break;
  }
  float temp = sorted.get(i-1);
  while (i > 1 && temp > val) {
    i--;
    temp = sorted.get(i-1);
  }
  if (temp > val) sorted.add(0, val);
  else sorted.add(i, val);
}
```

Just coded this on the editor so there might bugs but it should be something like this.

Comment: Can you give me more detail than "getting an error"? What kind of error? On which line?

Comment: Just modified my answer. I'm assuming it was a null pointer exception?

Comment: no it is having problems with the 'sorted.insert' are you allowed to just .insert into array list

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method insert(float) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Float>
 The method insert(int, float) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Float>
 The method insert(int, float) is undefined for the type ArrayList<Float>

 at FloatFromFile.main(FloatFromFile.java:47)

Comment: Ah, you're right. It's add instead of insert. Sorry. Editing my answer.